# What is the Linux distro ranking based on number of packages?

Tags: distribution-choice, distributions

I am looking for hard data for at least top 10 Linux distro or (better) an address of a web page which keeps such data and (maybe) updates it from time to time (after all repositories are public to view).

The criteria is -- the number of native (rpm for SUSE, deb for Ubuntu, etc.) packages programs, libraries, and available in repositories (not on install CD/DVD). For example library counts as 1, not as 10 just because there are 10 packages (ARM, Intel, SPARC, etc.) of it.

Thank you in advance.

*If you are interested why I am asking about this. Well, I am a bit tired searching repo, finding out there is no package, downloading zip/gz/bz2 of it, finding out how to make an rpm (in case of top layer software of another software, for example Rattle, it is not trivial task), and finally installing it. So it would be good for me to consider other distros which are higher in such ranking.*

Comment: Are you limiting this to official repositories?  I suspect Debian it may be Debian or Ubuntu.  Debian shows as having ~28442 'normal' packages on amd64 squeeze (`apt-cache show stats`).  But it doesn't have non-free or proprietary software, the non-free repository is pretty sparse.

Comment: No, I count official and semi-official, like Packman for openSUSE. I don't count "repositories" per 1 package, like for example Opera or VirtualBox.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions#Package_management_and_installation) you find some information, I don't know if accurate or not, I suspect not too much.

Anyway, each major Linux distribution has almost everything one can ever need. What is missing are essentially *niche* applications, or applications that in some way cannot be packaged.

Comment: It looks like Ubuntu and derivatives followed by Debian and derivatives are the top choices.

Comment: Technically, Ubuntu *is* a Debian derivative.

Comment: And I am very interested in niche applications, because as it turns out usually they are most difficult to repack (create rpm in my case) and also as I see my needs I am on the other side of "yet another wallpaper" usage of Linux. Thank you for the link, very useful!

Comment: The data on this page may be a bit outdated. Last time I looked Debian had ~36000 and Fedora ~25000 (so a few thousands more than what is mentionned on Wikipedia).

Answer (score 8):

This is in principle an objective question (count the number of packages available out there), but difficult to answer for lack of comparable figures.

If you count only packages that come with the distribution, then the [table in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions#Package_management_and_installation) (thanks to [enzotib](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20214/what-is-the-linux-distro-ranking-based-on-number-of-packages/20217#20217) for the link) gives the answer. Or rather it goes some way towards an answer: different distributions break up packages in different ways. For example SuSE tends not towards monolithic packages, so it has barely more binary packages than source packages. Debian, which usually separates anything that can sometimes be installed separately, has about the same number of source packages, but twice as more binary packages. All in all, most major Linux distributions (Ubuntu, Debian, Arch Linux including AUR, OpenSuSE, Fedora, Mandriva) have a similar amount of software.

There is more difference if you count third-party repositories and binary packages provided directly by vendors. Simply put, the more users a distribution has, the more people are inclined to make packages for it. I don't have any hard figures, but I suspect that Ubuntu is a winner here, both due to its large collection of user repositories¹ and due to the widespread support (because of Ubuntu's popularity). For enterprise software, Red Hat is also a strong contender.

¹ 
<sub>Personal package archives (PPA) — [entry point for users](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_PPAs), [entry point for developers](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

https://repology.org/repositories/statistics/nonunique

this kind of a count is good as long as the uniqueness is classified correctly, since the most popular software would find itself into AUR and NixOs repos becoming "nonunique"

Answer (score 1):

on Debian:

```
apt-cache pkgnames | wc -l
```

on RedHat:

```
dnf repoquery | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Comparison_of_Linux_distributions - Package_management_and_installation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions#Package_management_and_installation)

If you are looking for precompiled binaries it is different from if you are looking for sources.

See also [What is the best Linux distro for the most up-to-date packages?](https://www.slant.co/topics/8313/%7Elinux-distro-for-the-most-up-to-date-packages)

Comment: Your answer is verging upon being a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/280335). Could you please [edit] your answer and explain "how it is different"? What are differences and why do they matter? Try to include the relevant details from each of the links that you have posted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).